# python docx: ¿es posible copiar el esquema XML de un documento para crear un nuevo documento con este?

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un trozo de código en python donde tengo un documento base de Word y necesito completar algunas partes usando información de otro documento y luego devolver el documento base modificado.

Estoy usando la librería python-docx, siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

1. Subir el documento base y extraer el texto completo del mismo.
2. Subo el otro documento y extraigo la información que necesito.
3. Usando re library, sustituyo las partes del documento base que necesito por los datos del otro documento.
4. Crear el documento resultante. Aquí es donde tengo mi problema, ya que no sé cómo mantener la misma estructura (títulos, negritas, etc) del documento base al documento resultante. Así que mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna manera de copiar el esquema XML del documento base y utilizarlo para el documento resultante?

¿Tal vez debería editar el documento base en lugar de crear uno nuevo? No creo que sea lo mejor ya que necesito el texto completo para poder sustituir todas las partes que necesito, por eso estaba almacenando el texto completo en una variable, pero no se....

En fin,, cualquier ayuda es buena :) gracias

Comment: Después de haber hecho la sustitución sobre el documento base, no vale guardarlo con un nuevo nombre? Estoy suponiendo que allí ya tienes la versión final con la que te quieres quedar, no?

Comment: La cosa es que yo en ningún momento estoy editando el documento base, sino que estoy creando uno nuevo a partir de este. Me resulta más fácil hacerlo así para el momento de sustituir. Además, no acabo de tener claro cómo puedo editar los párrafos del texto base, he probado de un par de maneras pero no consigo que me salga ://

Comment: Quizás sea la descripción del punto 3 la confusa. Pero leyéndola de nuevo, me parece que podrías, si no lo haces aún, hacer la sustitución directamente sobre dicho documento, no?

Comment: Sin tener en cuenta las implicaciones de memoria que tiene cargar todo el texto del documento en una variable, diría que ese es el camino correcto para documentos pequeños. Que te preocupa de esa idea?

Comment: Con la memoria que suele estar disponible en el PC promedio hoy día, yo comenzaría a preocuparme si son documentos MUY grandes (en el orden de los gigabytes), lo cual no es muy común.

Comment: Vi tu publicación en inglés. La proxima, te recomiendo editar la pregunta (el botón editar está debajo de las etiquetas)

Comment: El problema que tengo al cargar todo el texto en una variable es que luego, al crear el nuevo documento, tengo que volver a aplicar el formato a todos los títulos, palabras en negrita, etc. y es algo tedioso (el documento no es muy largo pero es lo suficientemente largo como para que esta parte me lleve un tiempo considerable, por eso me preguntaba si habría alguna otra manera de hacer esto).